# Find coefficient in a linear combination

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

It's a very simple problem, but I don't find the way to solve it with Mathematica.

let's say $A=a+b$, $B=3a$, $G=b$. I want to find at least one (if any) solution to
$x A+ y B=G$
for $x,y$. 
I tried with this simple code:

```
FindInstance[x A + y B == G, {x, y}]
```

But I get the error:

```
FindInstance: the system contains a nonconstant expression a independent of variables {x,y}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `Reduce[A x + B y == G, {x, y}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include a [`ForAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll) quantifier:

```
FindInstance[ForAll[{a, b}, x A + y B == G], {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> 1, y -> -(1/3)}}

Comment: Alternatively, there is always `SolveAlways`. `In[65]:= SolveAlways[x*aA + y*bB == gG, {a, b}]

Out[65]= {{x -> 1, y -> -(1/3)}}`